# How to get reference to a dynamically added element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is intended to insert a `<p>` element into the `DOM` before an already existing `<p>` element and then insert a table below the newly inserted `<p>` element (so that the table appears between the two `<p>` elements):

```
$("#para1").before("<p id = 'para2'>" + printDate + "</p>");
$("#para2").after("<table id = 'table'></table>");
```

However, when I try to add a row to the newly inserted table, like so:

```
$("#table").prepend("<tr><td>asdfasf</td></tr>");
```

the row always gets added to a different table (with a diffrent id) that sits before the `<p>` element with id `para2`. What could be the reason for this strange behaviour?

This is a snapshot of the DOM inspector. How can the table with id `21-09-2014` be in two different places?

[image]

**EDIT**:
You were all correct. I had added an empty table with the same id earlier and thought it wasn't there because I couldn't see it. That brat cost me 5 hours of billable work!

Comment: No, that table has a different id

Comment: Duplicate IDs should be the only reason this would happen. Can you reproduce the issue in a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: Without the HTML (a JSFiddle or `Code Snippet`) this is mainly guesswork as your code should certainly work (if you do not have duplicate IDs on the page).

Comment: As the code is written it is impossible, is that the actual code you are using?

Comment: Do not use spaces around the "=" sign in HTML attributes.

Comment: Could you post the html of the first table?

Comment: @all: the table ids are definitely no the same. Could prepend be doing the mischief?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Does the edit help?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem for adding the entry to a different table might be duplicate `ids` in your page. If here are duplicate ids, the id selector will return the first element with the id.

To get the reference to newly added element use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) and [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead of [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) respectively.

```
var $para = $("<p id = 'para2'>" + printDate + "</p>").insertBefore('#para1');

var $table = $("<table id = 'table'></table>").insertAfter('#para2');
$table.append("<tr><td>asdfasf</td></tr>");
```

Comment: OP says they have different IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to prepend to a table? Shouldn't you use

```
$('#table tr:last').after('<tr><td>asdfasf</td></tr>');
```

instead?

or :first and before?

Comment: I want it to show as the first row in the table. Will this do that?

Comment: try tr:first and before

Comment: This should be the answer. Using append will not add row to the table correctly.

Comment: You can do an if: if($('#table tr').length == 0) { ($("#table tbody")).appendTo('<tr><td>asdfasf</td></tr>')

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#para1").before("<p id = 'para2'>The new p element with Id='para2' </p>");
$("#para2").after("<table id = 'table'><tr><td>The second row</td></tr></table>");

$("#table").prepend("<tr><td>new row inner #table and it will be the first row</td></tr>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-with-diferent-id">table with diferent id that already exist</table>
<p id="para1">para 1</p>
```